# PHP process does not die after time out

Tags: php, mysql, process

I have a PHP script with `set_time_limit(30)` on a CentOS VPS.  I'm monitoring the process list and after ten minutes it is still running.

It could be that my MySQL connection is taking longer than 30 seconds due to a bug.  How can I get the script to die and kill the MySQL connection?

I'm using a non-persistent connection -- `mysql_connect()`.  The `mysql_connect_timeout` setting is 60 seconds.

`max_input_time` is 300 seconds.  So I'm exceeding that as well.

Comment: `set_time_limit(30)` ??

Comment: PHP's set_time_limit timer does NOT count time spent in external systems, e.g. mysql. it only counts, literally, the time spent executing actual PHP code.

Comment: Sam - thanks. I fixed the typo.

Comment: Marc - Yes, but why doesn't the mysql connection timeout work?    Hmm, maybe it is having a problem processing GET or POST.  The script hangs very rarely -- so I don't know what the exact conditions are.

Comment: I think this is a result of a high `wait_timeout`: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/server-system-variables.html#sysvar_wait_timeout But I'm not sure so I'm not putting it as an answer. You should also consider calling `mysql_close()` in all situations [and using mysqli / PDO instead] rather than hoping PHP will clean it up nicely.

Comment: Actually scrap that - the PHP hang isn't to do with the MySQL resource not closing. PHP will fix that enough for the script to terminate. What are you trying to do in this script? I suspect you have a loop around something that does an external call.

Comment: The script fetches data from the database and displays it.  It is a client that uses the NuSOAP library to call a webservice to get the data.

Answer (score 0):

You need to change some setting in your php.ini :

```
max_execution_time = 30
; also, higher if you wish
```

Comment: How is `upload_max_size` relevant to this question?